# Presentation of the symmetric group $S_n$ like $D_n$?

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-presentation, permutation-cycles

I am trying to understand if there is a way we can define the $S_n$ group, just like we do for $D_n$. We know that $D_n$  is defined as $D_n =\langle r,s\mid s^2 = e, r^n = e, srs = r^{-1}\rangle$.
Can we do a similar definition for $S_n$?

I know that a transposition $(a,b)$ and a $n$-cycle $(1,2,3...,n)$ generate $S_n$ if and only if $\gcd(b-a, n) = 1$.
Using this, can we write something on the lines of
$S_n =\langle (a,b),r\mid|(a,b)| = 2, |r| = n,\gcd(b-a,n) = 1\rangle$?

I suppose we could add a relation among the two elements mentioned.
For example , for $S_4$, let $(a,b) = (12)$ and $r = (1234)$, then the relation
$r(a,b)r(a,b)r = (a,b)$ holds.
So, can I write $S_4 = \langle(a,b),r\mid|(a,b)| = 2, |r| = n,\gcd(b-a,n) = 1, r(a,b)r(a,b)r = (a,b)\rangle$?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: $\gcd(b-a,n)$ is not a relation between generators. It cannot be written inside a group presentation like you did. Neither can the writing of the transposition $t$ as $(a,b)$. And  $ |(a,b)| = 2, |r| = n$ must be replaced with $t^2=e,r^n=e$ (but of course there must be more relations).

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1718235

Comment: @AnneBauval i know gcd(b-a,n) is no a relation between relations, but it is a necessary and sufficient condition. You can look theorem 2.8 here https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/genset.pdf. So, I mentioned it in the definition.

Comment: I know it is a necessary and sufficient condition, but it doesn't allow to write a presentation like you tried to do.

Comment: @AnneBauval I know there are many relations possible for different symmetric groups. I am not looking for a generalized definition, but for any specific $S_n$, can we write it like this?

Comment: @AnneBauval Any other approach that I could look into?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "write it like this" (this writing tried to look like a presentation but had no precise meaning, as explained). Does this answer your question? [Find a set of generators and relations for $S_3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619245/find-a-set-of-generators-and-relations-for-s-3) Look at sections 4 (claim) and 5 (proof) of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/619488) to it.

Comment: There is a well-known Coxeter presentation of $S_n$ -- that should give you a buzzword to google.

Comment: @AnneBauval 'write like means', like how we  have a expression for $D_n$, two generator elements and a relation between them , I am looking for something on similar lines. A simple expression that will identify with the entire group.

Comment: The Coxeter [presentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group) (with many generators) was converted to a two-generators (but many relations) presentation, in the answer linked in my previous comment. So, once clarified, your post appears to be a duplicate.

Comment: Even though your post is specifically about $S_n$, it seems like you might profit from learning more about the concept of [group presentations](https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/fbouyer/presentation_of_group.pdf) in general. That would help, for example, in understanding the various comments to your post and the links within those comments.